# Google geocoding API stops running after SSL certificate Installed

Tags: google-maps, ssl

We have a mapping program that uses Googles geocoding API to generate a map from a database. Everything has been working fine. I just added an SSL certificate so we could iframe the map in a secure site, and now it won't work when I use https://. I have added the https:// URL to the list of approved URLs, and authenticated ownership of the https:// URL

This works fine:
http://www.2laketahoe.com/frames/tahoekeysframe.php

This starts to work, but doesn't get the google map:
https://www.2laketahoe.com/frames/tahoekeysframe.php

This is the javascript call that works:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=<?= $api_key ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use https embed code when using SSL.

try correcting this in your code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyDQMDo9qKjoi_QEBD1vvWvf4AHCm4OmXjE" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyDQMDo9qKjoi_QEBD1vvWvf4AHCm4OmXjE" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know why I didn't try this!  Problem solved.  Thank you very much!